# Let $f$ be a closed path in $S^1$ at $1$. Prove that if $f$ is not surjective, then $\deg f = 0$

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology

> Let $f$ be a closed path in $S^1$ at $1$.  Prove that if $f$ is not surjective, then $\deg f = 0$

Since $f$ is not surjective, there's a point in $S$ that it doesn't touch.  Which implies that the loop in $S$ never completely circles around the entire $S$.  Which implies $f \simeq c_1 \text{ rel } \{0,1\}$ the constant map at $1$.  Therefore $\deg f = \deg c_1$.  Now I just have to show the lift of $c_1$ at $1 = 0$.  Since $c(t) = 1 = exp \text{ lift $(c_1(t))$ }$ this implies that $\text{lift $c_1(t)$} \in \Bbb Z$.  But for the lift to be continuous it must be a constant map which is determined at $0$ since we're looking at degrees.

Am I assuming something incorrect at all or does this look fine?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it that way. The key is that there is a number $a\in(0,1)$
such that the lift of $f$ never takes the values $a$ or $a-1$. Thus
the lift starting at $0$ can never reach another integer (by the
Intermediate Value Theorem).

I'd do it a different way. The map $f$ maps into $S^1-\{\text{point}\}$
and this space is contractible: we can homotope $f$ to a point.